# How do I create and implement a free ssl certificate that does not raise a warning in a browser but simply ensures safe communication?

Tags: apache, openssl, ssl-certificate

That ensures safe communication being symbolized in the address bar.

I have an apache virtual server. I followed some tutorials but there is always this browser notification that it has to accept a certificate. And even after accepting the certificate, the page won't load. The php page itself is flawless, that's no source of error.

Share what one needs to know to create one's own certificates one can actually use, that means that raise no "accept certificate" or at least work after the certificate has been installed. I wouldn't write this here if the tutorials I came across so far weren't flawed.

Comment: If anyone could issue their own "safe certificate", there would be no purpose in certificates at all. Every malware/virus/spyware writer could just issue a "safe certificate".

Comment: A certificate is there to ensure safe transmission, encrypted communication. It is a crt file and all it does is exchange keys so communication can hardly be decrypted.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Ken White in the comments, for commercial usage or deployments, a privately issues certificate will never be a safe certificate.

But, if you wish to use it for testing purposes, then you can try installing the "Private CA's and Roots" of your Private Certificate in the corresponding browsers. You should refer to browser help on how to do this.

Comment: A certificate is there to ensure safe transmission, encrypted communication. It is a crt file and all it does is exchange keys so communication can hardly be decrypted by third parties between the server and you. You might be talking about something different here.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate your certificate and then get it signed for free by [StartCom](https://www.startssl.com/?app=1) as a Class 1 verified certificate.  With a class 1 verified certificate, you don't get the "green" symbol in the http address bar and the certification is minimal (i.e., your domain name and personal email) but it does get rid of the browser security warning.  The application process is much leaner than for "upper class" certifications.  It looks like you are looking for something like that.